# Fuzzy C-means clustering in ImageSegmentation.jl

Tags: julia, image-segmentation, fuzzy-c-means

I am trying to cluster different regions of an image using Fuzzy C-means clustering with ImageSegmentation.jl

```
using ImageSegmentation, Images
fl = load("flower.jpg")
fuzzy_fl = fuzzy_cmeans(fl,3,2)
```

It gives an error like this:

```
MethodError: no method matching fuzzy_cmeans(::Base.ReshapedArray{Float64,2,ImageCore.ChannelView{Float64,3,Array{ColorTypes.RGB4{Float64},2}},Tuple{Base.MultiplicativeInverses.SignedMultiplicativeInverse{Int64},Base.MultiplicativeInverses.SignedMultiplicativeInverse{Int64}}})
Closest candidates are:
  fuzzy_cmeans(::Array{T<:Real,2}, ::Int64, ::Real; maxiter, tol, dist_metric, display) where T<:Real at /Users/asharma19/.julia/v0.6/Clustering/src/fuzzycmeans.jl:58
  fuzzy_cmeans(::AbstractArray{T<:ColorTypes.Colorant,N}, ::Any...; kwargs...) where {T<:ColorTypes.Colorant, N} at /Users/asharma19/.julia/v0.6/ImageSegmentation/src/clustering.jl:12
```

1) How should I input an image to this function? 
2) Also, if it works fine, as the function does not return a SegmentedImage array, how should I display a segmented/clustered image after that?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me. You are probably taking a slice of the image manipulating it (e.g. views, transposes) before feeding it into the `fuzzy_cmeans` function. Something different than the code example you posted.

Comment: Did you try it in Julia 0.6? I cannot get this working. Also it would be great if you can help me with the second question.

Comment: The same image works for other algorithms perfectly. I have tried with original image too without any manipulation. Don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The function `fuzzy_cmeans` does not accept `Array{ColorTypes.RGB4{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}`.

The images need to be `Array{ColorTypes.RGB{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}` to be input in the function.

Although, it should not happen as the parameter type of the function is `Colorant{T,N}` which is the parent of `AbstractRGB{T}`.

The images usually are RGB4 (have some padding involved) so you need to convert them before using. (can use `convert` function of julia)